# Is there a way to avoid duplicate parameterized Jenkins builds?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, jenkins

I know in Jenkins you can avoid duplicate builds from running on top of each other by leaving the "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" checkbox unchecked.

However, the way it determines a concurrent build is just whether the job itself is running. I want it to determine concurrent build based on whether all the parameters that are passed into the job are the same.

So if I have a job in the queue with parameters foo and bar, then queuing one with foo and baz should actually queue, but queuing another with parameters foo and bar should just drop it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Jenkins will automatically kill off a queued job if the PREVIOUSLY queued job has the exact same parameters.  If a job is queued with parameters foo and bar, then the same job is queued with foo and bar again, the second instance is dropped.

In your example (first job with foo and bar, second job with foo and baz, third job with foo and bar), I believe that all jobs will be queued.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case. In particular, if a job with foo/bar for parameters is running, and you run the same job again, Jenkins happily runs both in parallel.

Comment: Correct - once a job is running, the checks don't seem to work.  The checking only seems to work for QUEUED jobs.  You might be looking for a new Jenkins feature - or perhaps a new Jenkins plugin.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like there isn't anything available at the moment, so I'll accept your answer. It helped me understand more of how it works, so thanks!